# how can we give color to "ngx-star-rating"?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have used ngx-star-rating plugin.
I tried various methods like fill & color but it doesn't work !
Any suggestions ? on what should I do for coloring the star-rating from yellow to any other color ?

Answer (score 2):

CSS selector `label.star:before` and attribute `color` is what you are looking for.

```css
input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: pink !important;
}
```

You can check [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-star-rating-goghwf?file=src%2Fstyles.css).

Comment: Its not working !! I tried putting it in style.scss

Comment: It works in the demo. I don't know what you are trying to apply without any working fiddle demo. Check the DevTools if your styles has been applied on `:before` element.

Comment: @Jax-p:can you tell me sir how to modify the font-size of ngx-star-rating?

Comment: @Kapilsoni CSS selector `label.star:before` and `font-size` attribute. Also `.stars` container attribute `width` is hard-coded to `270px` (it's not well written lib) and I could use `width: auto`. Something like [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-star-rating-lstzyf?file=src%2Fstyles.css).